# Does not work when selecting a file from the gallery

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, android-webview

Good evening, I ask to help, who can faced a similar problem and found a solution. There is a typical Android application for opening a page in WebView and the ability to download a file on this page. The problem is that the application works perfectly on 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 androids, it works on 5, 6, 7 and even 8 android, but on one particular device under the control of android 6, it does not want to work with file uploading ... Specifically, the problematic the device from which does not work to select the files - Xiaomi Redmi Note3 Build / MMB29M Android 6.0.1 If you look at the code on this machine, we see the message "mFilePathCallback == null", specifically deduced to understand what the hitch is - why this phone I can not get the result from activity ​​I can not understand, I need help ... What? and such a feature in Xiaomi devices can have as it is a different work? The code is typical, works wherever I tested, except for this device ...

what could be the problem?

MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mFilePathCallback == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};

                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

                if (clipData != null) {
                    results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                        results[i] = item.getUri();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data CL: " + results[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data CL ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data STR: " + results[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data STR ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no result from activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    return;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */);
    return imageFile;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://site.ru");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*;video/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AndroidExampleFolder");
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*;video/*");
            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});
            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    String webUrl = mWebView.getUrl();

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
                    if((webUrl.contains("url"))){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Attention")
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                    }
                    else
                    if((webUrl.contains("url"))){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "нажмите X кнопку.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    if((webUrl.contains("url")||(webUrl.contains("file:///android_asset/error_page.html")||webUrl.contains("url")))) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Attention")
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                    }else {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    }
                }else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Attention")
                            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.application">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Application"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Marshmallow (6.0) Onwards, you need to ask special permission (File READ/WRITE)at runtime also.
Follow this link
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java

Before, Android 6.0, 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

This used to work but 6.0 onwards it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the application works perfectly on 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 androids, it works on 5, 6, 7 and even 8 android, but on one particular device under the control of android 6, it does not want to work with file uploading

It will work sometimes on those versions of Android. It will not work all of the time.

> we see the message "mFilePathCallback == null"

Your process was terminated while your app was in the background. This is perfectly normal. You should get the same symptoms if you undergo a configuration change while an activity that you start is in the foreground. In either case, you wind up with a new activity when control returns to your all, and so your fields, such as `mFilePathCallback`, will be `null`.

Comment: I can not understand why it comes back mFilePathCallback is NULL a on one device, for others because the value is obtained and processed. Maybe there is something missing in the code of something?

Comment: @АлексейЗавьялов: It will come back `null` when your process is terminated, then restarted. Whether or not that will happen depends on a lot of things: how long the user is in the other app, how much memory is used by the foreground app, what other apps are running, how much free system RAM is on the device, the version of Android on the device, any manufacturer tweaks to the out-of-memory-killer algorithm, etc. **Do not assume that the devices that you think "work" will always work**.

Comment: @АлексейЗавьялов: Similarly, you are not handling configuration changes at all, which will give you the same sort of results.

Comment: @АлексейЗавьялов: You can test for this sort of effect, on any modern device, by going into Settings > Developer Options and turning on "Don't keep activities". This will destroy and recreate your activity on any navigation, and you will see the same results.

Comment: everything is completely wrong, the application does not close, it is in the active state all the time, activity only one application in the application, NULL is returned only on the Xiaomi device for an incomprehensible reason.

Comment: @АлексейЗавьялов: Somehow, your activity is getting destroyed and recreated. And, as I have noted previously, you will get this same problem for *any* reason why your activity is destroyed, such as configuration changes or your process being terminated. You have a bug in your app, where you assume that the same activity instance will be used for `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`. You need to fix that bug. Frankly, I do not know *how* you will fix that bug, other than by somehow getting rid of the need for the callback.

Comment: a little understood the problem. phone xiaomi when you call intent with the gallery of files, why it persistently closes the main activity webview, when we select a file, it opens it again, but the result is naturally nowhere to go. The application activity control mode for this application is disabled.